# I'm using Android Studio 4.1, and I can't get things to resolve. Please see the code below

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        String def;
        try {

            JSONObject  js = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray results = js.getJSONArray(name: "results");

            JSONObject   lEntries = results.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray laArray = lEntries.getJSONArray(name: "lexicalEntries");

            JSONObject entries = laArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray  e = entries.getJSONArray(name: "entries");

            JSONObject jsonObject = e.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray  d = de.getJSONArray(name: "definitions");

            def = d.getString(0);
            showDef.setText(def);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.v("Result of Dictionary", "onPostExecute" + result);
    }
}
```

index, tag, & msg all resolved after a little bit of finagling, but I can't get name to. Any ideas?

Maybe you can see what I'm talking about better in this screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Java 8 and older do not support named arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `compile 'org.json:json:20160212'` to your top `build.gradle`, like this :

```
dependencies {
   compile 'org.json:json:20160212'
}
```

If you already have the dependency then try the following :

```
File -> Invalidate caches/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart
```